# editing a text file in python and making a new one

Tags: python

I have a text file like this:

```
>ENST00000511961.1|ENSG00000013561.13|OTTHUMG00000129660.5|OTTHUMT00000370661.3|RNF14-003|RNF14|278
MSSEDREAQEDELLALASIYDGDEFRKAESVQGGETRIYLDLPQNFKIFVSGNSNECLQNSGFEYTICFLPPLVLNFELPPDYPSSSPPSFTLSGKWLSPTQLSALCKHLDNLWEEHRGSVVLFAWMQFLKEETLAYLNIVSPFELKIGSQKKVQRRTAQASPNTELDFGGAAGSDVDQEEIVDERAVQDVESLSNLIQEILDFDQAQQIKCFNSKLFLCSICFCEKLGSECMYFLECRHVYCKACLKDYFEIQIRDGQVQCLNCPEPKCPSVATPGQ
>ENST00000506822.1|ENSG00000013561.13|OTTHUMG00000129660.5|OTTHUMT00000370662.1|RNF14-004|GAPDH|132
MSSEDREAQEDELLALASIYDGDEFRKAESVQGGETRIYLDLPQNFKIFVSGNSNECLQNSGFEYTICFLPPLVLNFELPPDYPSSSPPSFTLSGKWLSPTQLSALCKHLDNLWEEHRGSVVLFAWMQFLKE
>ENST00000513019.1|ENSG00000013561.13|OTTHUMG00000129660.5|OTTHUMT00000370663.1|RNF14-005|ACTB|99
MSSEDREAQEDELLALASIYDGDEFRKAESVQGGETRIYLDLPQNFKIFVSGNSNECLQNSGFEYTICFLPPLVLNFELPPDYPSSSPPSFTLSGKWLS
>ENST00000356143.1|ENSG00000013561.13|OTTHUMG00000129660.5|-|RNF14-202|HELLE|474
MSSEDREAQEDELLALASIYDGDEFRKAESVQGGETRIYLDLPQNFKIFVSGNSNECLQNSGFEYTICFLPPLVLNFELPPDYPSSSPPSFTLSGKWLSPTQLSALCKHLDNLWEEHRGSVVLFAWMQFLKEETLAYLNIVSPFELKIGSQKKVQRRTAQASPNTELDFGGAAGSDVDQEEIVDERAVQDVESLSNLIQEILDFDQAQQIKCFNSKLFLCSICFCEKLGSECMYFLECRHVYCKACLKDYFEIQIRDGQVQCLNCPEPKCPSVATPGQVKELVEAELFARYDRLLLQSSLDLMADVVYCPRPCCQLPVMQEPGCTMGICSSCNFAFCTLCRLTYHGVSPCKVTAEKLMDLRNEYLQADEANKRLLDQRYGKRVIQKAL
```

I want to make a `list` in `python` for the 6th element of the lines that start with "`>`".
to do so, I first make a `dictionary` in python and then the keys should be the `list` that I want. like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
with open('infile.txt') as f:
    groups = groupby(f, key=lambda x: not x.startswith(">"))
    d = {}
    for k,v in groups:
        if not k:
            key, val = list(v)[0].rstrip(), "".join(map(str.rstrip,next(groups)[1],""))
            d[key] = val


k = d.keys()
res = [el[5:] for s in k for el in s.split("|")]
```

but it returns all elements in the line starts with `">".`

do you know how to fix it?

here is expected output:

```
["RNF14", "GAPDH", "ACTB", "HELLE"]
```

Comment: maybe you were confusing `groupby` and `filter`?

Answer (score 1):

This should help. ->Using a simple iterattion, `str.startswith` and `str.split`

**Demo:**

```
res = []
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith(">"):
            val = line.split("|")
            res.append(val[5])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['RNF14', 'GAPDH', 'ACTB', 'HELLE']
```

*In you code Replace*

```
res = [el[5:] for s in k for el in s.split("|")]
```

with

```
res = [s.split("|")[5] for s in k ] #Should work.
```

Comment: you forgot a `split('-')[0]` part missing in op's code but that gives the expected output

Comment: @bobrobbob. That is element#4 OP wants #5. I had the same confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

a solution near yours with filter instead of groupby and map

```
with open('infile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

groups = filter(lambda x: x.startswith(">"), lines)
res = list(map(lambda x: x.split('|')[5],groups))
```